# How to access variable outside js function

Tags: javascript

Probably trivial, but I have no idea how to do it... I want to access img outside of createThumbnail. How can I do that?

## Function

```
function createThumbnail(){
    canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll(); 
    html2canvas($('#chartdiv'), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
                elem = document.getElementById("thumbnail_img");
                elem.src = img;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**best is to return an object**. so you can "use" createThumbnail multiple times (this **isn't possible with a global variable**).

This way your code is nice and you don't make the function depending on your global scope / global variables.

```
function createThumbnail(){
    canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll(); 
    var img = {}, elem;
    html2canvas($('#chartdiv'), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            img.dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
            elem = document.getElementById("thumbnail_img");
            elem.src = img;
        }
    });
    return img;
}

var img = createThumbnail();
var dataUrl = img.dataUrl; // contains the dataUrl from the canvas when onrendered was called
```

Answer (score 3):

You are setting a local variable to the `onrendered` callback. Move that outside of the function and then just assign that variable from within the function.

```
var img; //Set empty variable here.

function createThumbnail(){
  canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
  html2canvas($('#chartdiv'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var elem;
      img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      elem = document.getElementById("thumbnail_img");
      elem.src = img;
    }
  });
}
```

See [this article about closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Comment: be aware that a function is good among other things to avoid redundancy. If you make the function depending on global variables, then the function is not a single unit anymore thus cannot be used multiple times without having problems and/or having messy code.

Comment: @sjkm No argument from me. I just wanted to form my answer in a way that made clear the scoping behavior OP was unclear on.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t by default, since `img` is declared inside the anonymous function. You’ll have to assign it to something accessible from the outside.

```
var accessibleImg;

function createThumbnail(){
    canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll(); 
    html2canvas($('#chartdiv'), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
                elem = document.getElementById("thumbnail_img");
                elem.src = img;
            accessibleImg = img;
        }
    });
}
```