# javascript - use a variable from another function javascript - 'today is not defined at Object'

Tags: javascript, scope

I try to get todays date to use it in an URL (concatenation) with a function. But, each time I've tried to run it, i have the same error : today is not defined at Object

I tried to declare it with and without var/let/const but the error stays. Does someone have an idea (console.log()) is just to test)?

```js
function GetTDDate() {
  today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
  console.log(today);
}

const FetchURL = "https://static.data.gouv.fr/resources/donnees-relatives-aux-personnes-vaccinees-contre-la-covid-19-1/20211221-212503/vacsi-tot-fra-" + today + "-21h25.json"
console.log(FetchURL)
```

Comment: Where are you actually declaring today. Because in that code you aren't declaring it which is why you need a var, let or const

Comment: make that function return `today`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access variable outside js function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812154/how-to-access-variable-outside-js-function)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want to do. Because the today variable is scoped to the function you should `return` it instead and then in the when defining `fetchURL` you can call your function to get access to the `today` variable.

Here is how you would do that:

```js
function GetTDDate() {
  let today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
  console.log(today);
  return today

}
const FetchURL = "https://static.data.gouv.fr/resources/donnees-relatives-aux-personnes-vaccinees-contre-la-covid-19-1/20211221-212503/vacsi-tot-fra-" + GetTDDate() + "-21h25.json"
console.log(FetchURL)
```

Comment: You need a *var*, *let* or *const* when declaring `today`.

Comment: Thanks I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
      var today = new Date();


      function GetTDDate() {
      var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
      var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
      var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

       today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
       console.log(today);

    const FetchURL = "https://static.data.gouv.fr/resources/donnees-relatives- 
   aux-personnes-vaccinees-contre-la-covid-19-1/20211221-212503/vacsi-tot-fra-" 
    + today + "-21h25.json"
     console.log(FetchURL)
```

Comment: your out of scope, either declare the variable outside the function or have the function return a value, the former is better

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution to your problem would be:

```js
const FetchURL = `https://static.data.gouv.fr/resources/donnees-relatives-aux-personnes-vaccinees-contre-la-covid-19-1/20211221-212503/vacsi-tot-fra-${(new Date()).toISOString().slice(0,10)}-21h25.json`;

console.log(FetchURL);
```

Comment: effectively this is easyer and working. thanks